# My black and white --> color effect broke, and I don't know why

Tags: jquery, css, tumblr, grayscale

So I finally got my black and white thing to work last night, but I did something wrong in the code and now I can't figure out what I did wrong. I've been looking for an hour. If anyone can help, that'd be great. The effect I'm trying to achieve is the images turn grayscale, and when you hover over them they turn to full color. The website this effect used to work and stopped working on is http://jamestestblog3.tumblr.com/. Thanks for anyone who can help.

Parts of the code that include the Grayscale Script:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.pryde-design.co.uk/projects/jQGreyScale/greyScale.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('.greyScale').hide().fadeIn(1000); // fade in the grayscaled images to avoid visual jump
      });
      $(window).load(function () { // user window.load to ensure images have been loaded
        $('.greyScale').greyScale({
          fadeTime: 500 // call the plugin with non-defult fadeTime (default: 400ms)
        });
      });

</script>

<img src="{PhotoURL-250}" class="greyScale" /></a>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the code in the question itself. I have no interest in digging through the entire HTML source of your page.

Comment: I edited it, please check now. I'm not sure if the problem itself actually lies in those portions of code, It may be another error, in which it would mean a lot if you COULD fish through the source.

Comment: The script currently crashes because `options` is undefined somewhere in the `infinitescroll` plugin (use Firebug and its console to see). Can you remember what you changed when it stopped working?

Comment: @Martin I have no clue whatsoever, sadly. :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've service ran over quota?

Looking at the console for your site, I can see this error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

and if you follow the link, it says you're over Quota:

> Over Quota
>
> This Google App Engine application is temporarily over its serving
>   quota. Please try again later.

here's [the link from your page I followed](http://img-to-json.appspot.com/?callback=_jqjsp&url=http%253A%2F%2F28.media.tumblr.com%2Ftumblr_lvn6fb1mr51qlmj75o1_250.jpg&_1323132852174=)

Comment: I have no clue what this means.. I'm 13 so I'm JUST learning Javascript.

Comment: @JamesCharlessDickinson Well, I'm much older than 13 and I have no clue what it means either. :P  Would be nice if a networker or someone who actually understands Hypertext Transfer Protocol could shed some light on it, but as far as I can tell, you are using a service to render b/w images.  That service is "over quota" and can't provide the service.  I would suggest just creating the b/w images yourself and uploading them to your server.  That way you don't have to rely on that google app and its capacity. :P

Comment: The website is a blog, actually a photo blog. It's not created with divs, it's created like posts. It's just like wordpress, except tumblr is easier to use. I can control what I post and the theme, but I don't have time to create a black and white version of every picture I reblog. (I reblog about 100 per day so..)

Comment: only other thing I can think of then is to use a library to convert your images.  Maybe something like PHP GD? http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: @Joesph - I don't get PHP at all and I don't think Tumblr accepts PHP. :( The Jquery script was working fine last night, and here's a working example (The tutorial demo): http://www.pryde-design.co.uk/projects/jQGreyScale/example.html

Comment: @JamesCharlessDickinson well it seems that same error appears on the demo site... I've also noticed that it creates a canvas element which has the grey scale version of the image.  This canvas element is not present in your example, but is probably generated manually.  I also noticed that you have several elements with the same ID... could you try the script with just one image and outside the infinite scroll?